# office-addin not loading from a nodejs spdy server, runs fine from local nodejs, express server

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an office-addin that runs fine on the outlook desktop (taskpane add-in). Everything works fine if I serve it from a local express server (I do run SSL through ngrok).

However, when I push the add-in to the production server, which runs nodejs spdy, I'm unable to load it. I get the "ADD-IN ERROR" "could not be started" message. I'm not able to get *any* debug information (outlook desktop logging or browser logging) that would indicate what the issue is. Manifest seems to check out fine in terms of the URLs pointing to the add-in "source" and I'm able to access the add-in "source" through the desktop browser and other means such as wget. So the files seem accessible through different paths.

I can't change the production server at all.

Is spdy a problem and if so, why?

Comment: Using the edge dev chooser and choosing the running "browser" embedded in outlook shows a pure blank instance of the browser. Are there any office365 outlook admin controls that might be affecting the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Outlook desktop using Edge HTML (not chromium) can only do TLSv1.1. Downgrading my server to allow TLSv1.1 using `minVersion: "TLSv1.1"` in the options worked.